# How can i change the value of an element in an object from extrareducer redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

This is the initial state:

```
const initialState ={
  ordersWholesale:[
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "XTPara 650mg Tablet",
      "code": "XTP5656",
      "date": "17/10/2022",
      "accepted": null,
      "wholesale": "shakthi",
      "quantity": "5"
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "name": "Dolo 650 Tablet",
      "code": "DOL1213",
      "date": "17/10/2022",
      "accepted": false,
      "wholesale": "shakthi",
      "quantity": "5"
    },
  ],
}
```

This is the slice reducer

```
extraReducer: {
  [asyncOrderAccept.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {

  }
}
```

How can I change only the value `orderWholesale[0]['accepted']: true` using the payload value which is 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly that the action payload is the `id` of the `ordersWholesale` state element you want to toggle true, then you'll need to search the array to find the correct element by `id` and then update *that* element. Keep in mind that `state` ***is*** the `ordersWholesale` array and that `Array.prototype.find` potentially returns undefined if no match is found.

```
extraReducer: {
  [asyncOrderAccept.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
    const el = state.find(order => order.id === payload);
    if (el) {
      el.accepted: true,
    }
  },
}
```

This may also work for you if you can use Optional Chaining.

```
extraReducer: {
  [asyncOrderAccept.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
    state.find(order => order.id === payload)?.accepted = true;
  },
}
```